# How to do Clobber trunk. I finished point one and two. I did it on Unix box. But i am having trouble in point 3,4,5

Tags: svn

1. Do an “svn export” on the branch to get all the files without the Subversion metadata.
2. Check out the Trunk to get a working copy.
3. Identify all the files that exist on the Trunk but not in the export branch and delete them (via Subversion) in the Trunk working copy.
4. Do an OS copy from the export directory to the Trunk working copy.
5. Identify all the add files from branch(not under Subversion control) and get them added.
6. Execute a “record-only” merge from the branch to the Trunk.
7. Execute a commit.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do a normal merge? Perhaps with the "--accept" flag to specify which side of any conflict to use?

Comment: Whenever we distrust the contents of a branch (including the Application Trunk), we use the “Clobber” technique to get it to a state that we can trust.  
A merge will not work, because any files that are not replaced by the merge will remain in the repository, continuing to provide a source of confusion and inaccuracy.

Comment: Why would a merge fail to delete or move files deleted or moved on the branch?

Comment: I am not able to understand, what exactly you are trying to say?

Comment: If you use svn commands to delete files on a branch, when you do an svn merge, those file deletions will propagate from the branch to the trunk. I don't understand why "any files that are not replaced by the merge will remain in the repository" after a merge.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is probably to use a tool that can diff directory contents, like Beyond Compare, Meld, WinMerge, WinDiff, kDiff3, etc.